# Apache Camel convert Plain Text file to JSON or Class Object

Tags: json, templates, serialization, apache-camel, plaintext

I would like to create a dataFormat to parse this text below into JSON

```
COMPAY-O.S. TITLE TEXT - TEST 105/2014 BR
A
COMPANY .: MY COMPANY LTDA                             CGC : 00999999/0001-99
CITY ....: BELO HORIZONTE                              UF .: MG
PHONE ...: (11)5555-1234     //  (11)5555-4321         FAX : (11)5555-1234
EMAIL ...: MYADDRESS@GMAIL.COM
A/C .....: JOHN DOE
```

Desired output:

```
{ company: 'MY COMPANY LTDA', cgc: '00999999/0001-99', city: 'BELO HORIZONTE', uf: 'MG', phone: '(11)5555-1234     //  (11)5555-4321', fax: '(11)5555-1234', email: 'MYADDRESS@GMAIL.COM', 'a/c': 'JOHN DOE'}
```

What should I use in this case?

Using camel-core v2.19.1

Answer (score 0):

I think [flatpack](http://camel.apache.org/flatpack.html) is the way to go, although I have never used it before. It generates a Map object from your input which you can then convert to a json object

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on that